# dotnet core on ubuntu 14.04 upstart issue

Tags: .net, nginx, upstart, dotnet-cli, .net-core

I got dotnet core 1.0 running on a ubuntu 14.04 vm. I'm attempting to write an upstart script for my deployment process:

```
start on filesystem and started networking
respawn
chdir /home/dotnetuser/dotnetportal/
exec sudo /usr/bin/dotnet restore
exec sudo /usr/bin/dotnet run
```

After running this service, I verify the logs and get what is normally expected (from testing locally/development vm):

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/dotnetuser/dotnetportal
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I have the localhost:5000 on an nginx reverse proxy for my domain and ssl:

```
server {
   # Enable HTTP/2
       listen 443 ssl; #http2;
       listen [::]:443 ssl; #http2;
       server_name portal.secret.com;

       # use the lets encrypt certificates
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.secret.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/portal.secret.com/privkey.pem;

      # include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
      include snippets/ssl_params.conf;

     location / {

         proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }

}
```

However when I curl https://portal.secret.com/ I verify the logs again and I get a bunch of compiler errors.

**Keep in mind that I DO NOT Get any errors when running dotnet run directly from the working production folder and I am able to access the site.**

The logs when I try and run the site from the service is:

```
an unhandled exception has occurred: Can not find compilation library location for package '    microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery'
 18 System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find compilation library location for package 'microsoft    .aspnetcore.antiforgery'
 19    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
 20    at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__157`2.MoveNext()
 21    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(    IEnumerable`1 parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature ETC.....
```

Does anybody have any insights as to why this is happening only when I'm upstarting a service and not when running the command directly?

UPDATE: Here is my Project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "xxxxx",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "System.Runtime.Loader": "4.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-update1",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-update1",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "MongoDB.Driver" : "2.3.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "WebApplication"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project.json? Do you have `preserveCompilationContext` set?

Comment: Thanks for responding, yes this build option is set to true. See my updated post for the project.json.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing the /tmp/NuGetScratch folder and also explicitly told linux which user to run the app under. The updated service conf script is:

```
start on filesystem and started networking
respawn
 setuid dotnetuser
 env HOME=/home/dotnetuser
 exec rm -rf /tmp/NuGetScratch/
 chdir /home/dotnetuser/apps/dotnetportal
 exec dotnet restore
 exec dotnet run
```

The issue was that .net was not compiling because of file permission issues caused by the nuget lock files that are found in the directory I removed (tmp/NuGetScratch). I guess for now .net expects you to run as root - found about this here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/78 (the NuGet cache population fails because /tmp/NuGetScratch is owned by root or some other su)